# Unified validation DSL for client-side & server-side

Tags: validation

I work for an eCommerce company and we want to use some kind of unified validation DSL for validating data both client-side and server-side. Does anyone know of such a tool / library?

Comment: Out of interest, I just found this: http://www.google.com/patents/US8756579

Comment: Should a DSL not do this out of the box?

Comment: How would that work?